# Microsoft translator API - notranslate option not working with Neural Network MT

Tags: microsoft-translator, machine-translation, neural-mt

Does anyone experience notranslate option is ignored when sending to  Microsoft Neural Network MT?  The same string works with SMT. I am sending this with "text/html".

My example string:

```
<p>For example, it is important to install the latest <span class=\"notranslate\">Intel® Chipset Software Installation Utility</span> immediately after installing most Microsoft operating systems to ensure proper drivers for the chipset are installed prior to installation of other drivers. System integrators should confirm boxed Intel Core 2 Duo processor-based systems are optimally configured and integrated.</p>
```

Furthermore, if I have href wrapped around a string with "notranslate" option, the whole link will be disappeared after NMT.

```
"target_content": "<p>Beispielsweise ist es wichtig, die neueste Intel® Chipset Software Installation Utility unmittelbar nach der Installation der meisten Microsoft-Betriebssysteme zu installieren, um sicherzustellen, dass die richtigen Treiber für den Chipsatz vor der Installation anderer Treiber installiert werden. System Integratoren sollten bestätigen, dass Boxed Intel Core 2 Duo Prozessor-basierte Systeme optimal konfiguriert und integriert sind.</p>", 
"source_content": "<p>For example, it is important to install the latest <a href=\"http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&amp;ProductFamily=Chipsets&amp;ProductLine=Chipset+Software&amp;ProductProduct=Intel%c2%ae+Chipset+Software+Installation+Utility\"><span class=\"notranslate\">Intel® Chipset Software Installation Utility</span></a> immediately after installing most Microsoft operating systems to ensure proper drivers for the chipset are installed prior to installation of other drivers. System integrators should confirm boxed Intel Core 2 Duo processor-based systems are optimally configured and integrated.</p>"
```

Comment: are you using html content type?

Comment: yes, sending as text/html